# PXGrid can insert only single row

Tags: c#, erp, acumatica

I have a **PXGrid** and a **Checkbox** control, there is a checkbox in the head container and the grid is in a detail container. I want it so when the checkbox has *value* = **"true"**, the grid can be filled with multiple rows and if the checkbox *value* = **"false"** or **null**, the grid can only be filled single row.

[image: Checkbox in head container]
[image: PXGrid in detail container]

I have tried the following code, but it's doesn't work for me.

```
    protected virtual void BSMTNotification_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row == null) return;

        BSMTNotification head = (BSMTNotification)e.Row;

        if(head.Breakdown == false || head.Breakdown == null)
        {
            if(NotificationActivities.Select().Count != 0)
            {
                NotificationActivities.AllowInsert = false;
                NotificationActivities.Cache.AllowInsert = false;
            } 
        }
        else
        {
            NotificationActivities.AllowInsert = true;
            NotificationActivities.Cache.AllowInsert = true;
        }
    }
```

Sorry my English is bad, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct but you should call it from NotificationActivity_RowInserted and NotificationActivity_RowDeleted too. like that:

```
protected virtual void NotificationActivity_RowInserted(PXCache sender, PXRowInsertedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row == null) return;

    BSMTNotification head =  BSMTNotifications.Current;

    if(head.Breakdown == false || head.Breakdown == null)
    {
        if(NotificationActivities.Select().Count != 0)
        {
            NotificationActivities.AllowInsert = false;
        } 
    }
    else
    {
        NotificationActivities.AllowInsert = true;
    }
}
```

Setting only   NotificationActivities.AllowInsert is enough. It is not required to set   NotificationActivities.Cache.AllowInsert too.

Also you should make sure that Breakdown checkbox has 'CommitChanges=true' property in .aspx

Comment: thank you for your advice, I've tried to suggestions from you, but the grid can still be filled with more than one row if data has not been saved.
What other ways exist to resolve such a case?